# ImportError: No module named 'tkinter' - `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

`python --version` 3.5.8

`sudo find / -name "*tkinter*"`

```
outputs
/snap/core/8592/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter
/snap/core/8689/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/test/test_tkinter
/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-38m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__pycache__/_tkinter_finder.cpython-37.pyc
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/future/moves/tkinter
/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_tkinter.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter
```

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk` python3-tk is already the newest version (3.7.3-1ubuntu1)

`python -c "import tkinter"` - ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'

before I `find ~/.pyenv/ -name "*tkinter" | xargs rm -rf`'d I was getting the `No module named '_tkinter'` error

I am using *pyenv* and have tried re-installing my env with `pyenv install 3.5.8`.

I think with all the uninstalling/reinstalling I've been doing my backend is out of whack. What are my "hard reset' options here?

Comment: As the current Python version reported is `3.5.8` and its modules are installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/`, it seems like that this version of Python is built using source.  Try to rebuild and install from the source with tkinter support.

Comment: I went through https://www.python.org/search/ but any reference to tkinter is Mac-based :/

Comment: I tried building 3.5.0, 3.5.6 from source (I need 3.5 for Zipline). Keep getting "The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _dbm                  _gdbm              
_tkinter"

Comment: Do you have tcl/tk development packages installed in your Linux?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install tcl` from https://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/ shows it's installed. Downloading source from the same website now

Comment: Development package is something like `tk-dev` and `tcl-dev` for debian based Linux.

Comment: both installed. Fortunately, 19.10 came 2 days ago and the tkinter backend was reinstalled. In the future people with this problem _could_ fix it by upgrading their OS `update-manager -d`. You are likely already at the latest version though and upgrading to a _dev_ version to solve this problem should be last resort